# How to prevent reloading the entire component on updating some firestore documents?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, drag-and-drop

I am trying to build a drag and drop to do list...After every drag and drop position of each element is updated in firebase...This is the function doing so

```
unfinishedTodos.forEach((each, index) => {
 firebaseApp.firestore().collection("todos").doc(each.id).update({
   index: index})
});
```

But after the update function is run the entire component is reloading..The problem is that since there are lots of items in the list I have to again scroll to find the item i was working with...I want to make sure that the firestore documents get updated but the page should not reload...How can I can prevent this reload?
**Update:**
I found out what went wrong...Actually I was using the onSnapshot function of firebase...So on every change it got triggered and reloaded the data...

Comment: Could you show the entire component where you do this? It should be quite easy but it'll be helpful to see the context of this.

Answer (score 1):

React updates a component whenever any `state` or `props` variable changes.

So, to prevent a re-render conditionally, you can use this lifecycle function (returning `false` means avoiding a re-render):

class component

```
shouldComponentUpdate(prevState, prevProps) {
    if (this.state.someVariable !== prevState.someVariable || 
        this.props.someVariable !== prevProps.someVariable) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

functional component

```
React.memo(MyComponent, (props, nextProps)=> {
    if(this.state.someVariable !== prevState.someVariable) {
        // if don't re-render/update
        return true
    }

    //...
})
```

Comment: But I am using a functional component not a class component..How should I modify your code if that is the case

Comment: added it to my answer

Comment: Hey but I don't understand on updating the firebase firestore database i am not changing any state or props of the current component...So what is the reason for re-render of entire component?

Comment: Well it's obvious that if you change the data, which your app is "subscribed" to, the components re-render. Obviously this "subscription" must mean passing the data through props, under the hood (everything in React is passed this way). Sorry, I can't be more specific, as I don't know `firebase`...